# ios iAd loading before displaying

Tags: ios, swift, iad, interstitial

I'm working on a iOS game in swift.
I'm trying to add an interstitial ad.
What I would like to do is when the game is over, displaying an Ad.
After closing it, the user can launch another game.
When the game is over I call this method:

```
   func showFullScreenAd() {
        if requestingAd == false {

            interstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
            interstitial!.delegate = self

            requestingAd = true

        }

    }

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {


        if interstitial?.loaded==true{
             ....}
}
```

The ad will be displayed when interstitialAdDidLoad is called.
So, between showFullScreenAd() and interstitialAdDidLoad some times we may have several seconds (the time for the ad to load) so the user can click on 'new game' and starts the game.
So, the game will begin and then the ad will be displayed (I'm handling the pause mode also) but it's weird to start the game and to have the ad showing up.

I'm thinking about the following case: 
doing

```
interstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
```

when loading the game
and when the game is over just show the ad (if available), and doing it again after that.

What do you think about this ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the ad onto the view as a subview right? So load it and add it to the view when you are ready to. I'm assuming that you're doing it before interstitialAdDidLoad at the moment?